# Can't Count Chars in a String

Tags: c++, string, counter

It always comes out 0 and 0, I'm just trying to count the Gs and Cs (and non-Gs and Cs) in the string given by a user. I know this is a beginner problem, sorry about that :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int x = 0
int y = 0

string s;

cout << "Enter a sequence" << endl;
cin >> s;

for (int i = 0; i > 100; i++)
    if (s[i] == 'g' || s[i] == 'c')
        x += 1;
    else
        y += 1;

cout << x << endl;
cout << y << endl;

}
```

Comment: There's an algorithm for this: `std::count_if`.

Comment: Please provide an example of input and output.

Comment: @chris HA! not this time :P

Comment: Sorry about the stupid mistake. But now it says 3 - 97, because it also counts the empty spaces. Is it possible to somehow only count what the user inputs?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Meh, I gave no usage or anything, and it's probably not the easiest solution for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realise

```
for (int i = 0; i > 100; i++)
```

never runs, right?

You're saying - "let `i` be `0`... as long as `i > 100` (lol - never) do something".

You probably meant

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
```

or you can use `std::count_if`.

Comment: `i < s,size()`. Now that would be a pain to track down if `size()` was a valid free function.

Answer (score 1):

for (int i = 0; i > 100; i++)

Since 0 is not greater than 100, this loop executes zero times.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, it should `i < 100`